How can I calculate a generate loop control value from a module parameter?
I have a module which has an integer parameter. This parameter controls a generate loop. When the parameter value is 0, then it cannot be used but must be replaced by 1. I tried to use a function, but the function can only initialize a variable, which cannot be used for the control of the generate loop. This is my example code which gave this error message

Unable to bind parameter `number'

for the code line with the generate instruction:
module test
    #(parameter
        g_latency = 8
    )
    ;
    function integer get_number;
        begin
            if (g_latency==0) begin
                get_number = 1;
            end else begin
                get_number = g_latency;
            end
        end
    endfunction

    genvar i;
    integer number;

    initial begin
        number = get_number;
    end
    generate for (i=0; i<=number-1; i=i+1)
        begin: step_g
            // comment
        end
    endgenerate
endmodule


So, how can I calculate a generate control value from a module parameter?

You can use another parameter instead of a function to create the compile-time constant:
module test
    #(parameter
        g_latency = 8
    );

    localparam NUMBER = (g_latency==0) ? 1 : g_latency;

    genvar i;
    generate for (i=0; i<=NUMBER-1; i=i+1)
        begin: step_g
            initial $display("%m i=%0d g_latency=%0d", i, g_latency);
        end
    endgenerate
endmodule

module tb;
    test #(0) i0 ();
    test      i1 ();
endmodule

Output:
tb.i0.step_g[0] i=0 g_latency=0
tb.i1.step_g[0] i=0 g_latency=8
tb.i1.step_g[1] i=1 g_latency=8
tb.i1.step_g[2] i=2 g_latency=8
tb.i1.step_g[3] i=3 g_latency=8
tb.i1.step_g[4] i=4 g_latency=8
tb.i1.step_g[5] i=5 g_latency=8
tb.i1.step_g[6] i=6 g_latency=8
tb.i1.step_g[7] i=7 g_latency=8


I prefer this solution, because it eliminates the function. Also I do not like using the function in the generate and using a variable  calculated  by the function in other parts of the module. My implementation know is this: localparam c_nr_of_steps        = (g_latency==0) ? g_dividend_width : $ceil(g_dividend_width/g_latency); localparam c_dividend_width_ext = (g_latency==0) ? g_dividend_width : $ceil(g_dividend_width/g_latency) * g_latency; localparam c_nr_of_periods      = (g_latency==0) ?                1 : g_latency;

Try this:
module test
    #(parameter
        g_latency = 8
    )
    ;
    function integer get_number;
        begin
            if (g_latency==0) begin
                get_number = 1;
            end else begin
                get_number = g_latency;
            end
        end
    endfunction

    genvar i;
    integer number;

//     initial begin
//       number = get_number;
//     end
  
  // ok to use the function as part of the generate statement
  generate for ( i=0; i<= get_number() - 1; i = i + 1 )
        begin: step_g
            // comment
        end
  endgenerate
  
endmodule

It produces 0 errors, 0 warnings for me using the commercial simulators on www.edaplayground.com.
